# How to make user can't access the tabbar in home page based on condition

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, tabbar

I write the following code inside the function and call that into `viewWillAppear` method.

I want to disable to Tabbar Bottom items access.

Here `TabarVC()` is `TabBarView` controller class name.

```
let tabbar = TabarVC()
tabbar.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Show the whole code in which run `let tabbar = TabarVC()
tabbar.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController ,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}


func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController.isKind(of: twoViewController.self as AnyClass) {
      return true  
    } 
    if viewController.isKind(of: threeViewController.self as AnyClass) {
      return false
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working twoViewController and threeViewController is the tabbar pages names.

Comment: Yeah these are pages name of TABBAR